# Owner Window - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a new Window on WPF project, but when Show the Child Windows is not inside the father

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myWindow = new Window2();
    myWindow.Owner = this;
    myWindow.Top = this.Top + 10; myWindow.Left = this.Left + 100;
    myWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: If you don't care much about specifying exact distance from the parent corner you can use `<Window WindowStartupLocation="CenterParent">` or  `<Window WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner>` in your child window.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "inside the father". Do you mean a typical MDI look, or a new window that pops up in front of the Window that has created the child window?

Comment: Yes a typical MDI application, if I use a panel as a toolbar or DataGrid ub, it is clear that should remain within the window that called them (father).